# Use internet connection from one server in second server

Tags: networking, server

I have two servers running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and both have two network interfaces configured using `/etc/network/interfaces` since **I do not use NetworkManager**.

Server1 is connected to the internet on network interface 1, while network interface 2 is used to connect to Server2. 
I can do **SSH** from Server1 to Server2 without any issues. However, Server2 is not connected to the internet.

How can I share Server1/interface1's internet connection with Server2/interface2?

`/etc/network/interfaces` looks like below;

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
allow-hotplug em1

iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.1.70
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto em2
allow-hotplug em2
iface em2 inet static
address 192.168.2.72
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**Edit** 
In response to the comments :
"internet" -> srv1/int1 
srv1/int2 <-> srv2/int2

where "internet" is a single ethernet socket which is connected to the router, which is in another room. I'm planning to buy a router, but for the moment I need an interim solution to connect srv2 to the internet (to allow installing/updating packages).

Comment: Hi There, Correct me if I'm wrong. Both your servers have 2 NIC's each. Svr1 / int1 has internet while svr2 / int2 is connected to svr2 / int2? Now, could you please tell me from where svr1 / int1 is getting internet? through a router? I would simply use a switch or even the existing device based on what I have... Add more in detail about the network/internet.. :)

Comment: Good stuff! Now tell me.. Does that router issue IP addresses?? or are you configuring static IP's

Comment: Try looking [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup Server1**

Configure iptables for NAT translation so that packets can be correctly routed through Server1:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o em1 -i em2 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT   
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING    
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o em1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Save new added iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav
```

and add the following line before the `"exit 0"` in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav
```

Configure Server1 for routing between two interfaces by enabling IP forwarding:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

Open `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**Setup Server2**

em1 is the network card on Server2 which is connected (by crossover cable) to em2 on the Server1. Any IP address can be set for em1 in Server2, as long as it matches the subnet (192.168.2.0/24) of em2 in Server1, for example: 192.168.2.100

Stop networking

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
```

Add default gateway for em1 in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.72
```

> This address should match the IP address of em2 in Server1.

Edit /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;
```

> 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google DNS. If you wish to use your ISP's DNS servers, just replace them.

Restart networking

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Now Server2 should have the internet connection shared from Server1.

Comment: Does this solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks @tungtns, sorry for the late reply. I followed your instructions but it doesn't work, i.e. I ping from srv2 but it just hangs. Note that I don't have a crossover cable, I thought that this is not needed with recent network interfaces, and also on srv2 I only have /etc/dhcp/, not /etc/dhcp3/. Do you have some suggestions to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I've updated the answer a bit. You can edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. And yes you don't need a crossover cable for current modern network interfaces. Which IP did you try to ping? An internet IP or an IP of Server1?

Comment: I tried an external IP.

Comment: It worked after a reboot  of both machines

Comment: That's it. I forgot. You must restart your server after enabling IP forwarding. Thanks for responding.